# Crystal Report Runtime software from server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

advanced hello to all

I made an application in C# , in that app I have some report created with crystal report
is there any way to running this report without installation crystal runtime in clients machine

maybe using crystal report that installed on server ?

thanks 
farzad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is no way to run a Crystal Report on a computer without installing the client components locally. You could, however, develop a service running on the server machine, which takes a report from a client, renders it to PDF (for example) and sends the results back for displaying on the client. This wouldn't be a simple task though, since you might also have to consider further input from the client (like report parameters, which you can't even determine at runtime without the client components) and have to implement communication over the network.

Otherwise, maybe you are more interested in a web-based approach and need [Crystal Reports Server](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-server/index.html)?

Comment: I know it's probably not what you wanted to hear, but if it helped I'd appreciate if you could mark it as answer. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know when and who will need the report you can use a scheduler. There are few vendors who produce schedulers for Crystal reports. The way how it works is : You will choose the report, the parameters , the export type (PDF, Excel, Word, HTML etc.) and the time when the report should be started. The scheduler will run the report, export it and deliver it. Depending on the scheduler you might be able to deliver the exported files to a network drive , e-mail address, SharePoint etc. Her is a link to an article comparing different schedulers:
http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines